# How do I pause and resume apt-fast package download?

Tags: apt-fast

I know that in order to speed up apt-get downloads, I can use apt-fast (which uses the aria2c or axel engine - it depends on which one I install during the configuration). But even though it says it can pause and resume downloads, I don't know how to do it,  and I can't find any answer online that tells me how to do it.

I have no intention of pausing apt-fast update function, I just want the ability to pause the sudo apt-fast install package_name function and resume the downloading of a package in Ubuntu at will using apt-fast (with axel or aria2c)

I have seen in some forums that sudo apt-fast update cannot be paused because it requires starting the entire process. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is not possible to interrupt current downloads smoothly. But if you cancel those downloads with a signal (e.g. pressing `^C`) and if you are using aria2 you can easily continue downloading later. Axel does not support continuation of aborted downloads (and is therefore not recommended for apt-fast).

If you have already downloaded some files via aria2 and cancel the download they aren't available for APT until all downloads with apt-fast are finished.

And on the other side if you cancel an apt-get/aptitude/synaptic/etc. download you have to start from scratch with apt-fast. But of course if some packages are already downloaded successfully and therefore are in your archive cache (usually `/var/cache/apt/archives`) apt-fast will ¨detect¨ them and don't add it to download queue again.